# Chance of shock?

Tags: power

We had issue of earthing at home and this electrician asked me to remove sleepers and touch his hand while he checks the main power board.Note that he's standing on wooden board. If i am not wrong then completing the circuit will give me shock. Am i wrong? Isn't that guy checking circuit by checking it on me?

Comment: It will shock you worse them him most likely, don't test for power by touching people, use a multimeter.

Comment: Or just a screwdriver with phase detector...where are you form? I want to be sure that I'm not going to call that electrician :)

Comment: @mahesh what are you going to do now?

Comment: Get a Darwin Award ready to give this guy (postumously, of course, which is the only way Darwin Awards can be given, by definition).

Comment: @OlinLathrop, if it does not kill you but does render you unable to reproduce you can still get a darwin award, by definition. : )

Comment: @Kortuk: Yes, good point.  Maybe you shouldn't be holding the electrician's *hand* then.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, Now I giggled at the original comment, but that got me to really really laugh.

Comment: @Kortuk: Why would this shock the "assistant" more that the electrician? Aren't they connected in series?

Comment: @sharptooth, I was tired, it used to be very common in a static electricity system that the last in the chain takes the largest shock, both people are going to be in deep trouble here.

Comment: @Kortuk: I don't get that - why would it matter who was the last in the chain?

Comment: @sharptooth, It is not something I honestly say I know why, they used to use a large Van de Graaff generator and then would form a large line of people holding hands and one end would touch it and the others would bounce in the air supposedly increasing in height as they went. This is something they told me at a museum with many old electronics and one of these generators in Italy, they could be misrepresentations of the truth as I cannot find links at all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Obviously a very very bad idea, as all have said so far.

This suggests that the man concerned is not qualified to do the job that he is doing. It also suggests that the work he does is suspect and may be dangerous. Trusting his work may cost you your house or your life.

Any electrician involved in this sort of work MUST have a multimeter as a basic tool. It does not matter what country, what level of poverty or income is involved - a minimal test tool  is required.

You can make this sort of test using a "neon" tester (neon bulb with a resistor in series with two test probes) with a fair degree of certainty re dead or alive BUT a multimeter can tell you much more.

---

**When it's a matter of life and death -**

- **Doing it by hand - More Safely BUT NOT TOTALLY SAFELY!**

Be aware that when subject to electric shock, arm and hand muscles (and other limbs / muscles contract) and above a certain level it is impossible to release your grip.

If you ever **MUST** use your body to test for a live conductor situation
 (and you'd REALLY be better restricting this to life and death situations)
  then clench your fist tightly and test with a tap of the middle back of your hand. ie with your clenched fingers pointing way from the conductor,and with your arm held so that when/if the muscles contract your hand will be pulled away from contact with the live connection. What this does is to prevent you accidentally grasping the conductor and not being able to release your grip due to muscle contraction due to electric shock, (as happens)  -
 SO THAT if you do get a shock, and the arm muscles contract, it will pull your hand away from the conductor and out of contact

Note that the above will PROBABLY keep you from dying - but please do not complain to me if it doesn't.
 **ANY CONTACT WITH MAINS VOLTAGES CAN KILL**

When doing anything as silly and in-advised as this it pays to have a second person present **and NOT touching you** when you do this AND ensure they are trained how to handle an electric shock situation..

My brain tells me that I have used this method long ago. My brain may be wrong. Using a multimeter hurts less :-).

Comment: -1 for explaining how to do it by hand, even if you say this is "almost safe".

Comment: @FedericoRusso But I think that the message is clear. Bold matters

Comment: @clabacchio - I kind of agree with Federico: no matter how many warnings you add this is not safe and should never be recommended, even with disclaimers.

Comment: @stevenvh I may be wrong, but I didn't know about these precautions; and I think that in the extreme case in which I would have to check if something can shock me, I would prefer doing as Russel said instead of risking that my hand clamps to a wire. Not that I will really try, but it's something to keep in mind and that can be applied in less dangerous situations also.

Comment: @russellMcMahon, I approved a minor edit to your post, I lightly improved the suggestion, I think the English may not have been clear to someone that is still learning English and is not at a year of practicing reading your style of writing.

Comment: @stevenvh, I am actually a large fan of telling people it is a terrible idea but telling them what the major flaws are. I think it is valuable to tell people not to do something dangerous but it is also valuable to explain what exactly makes the task deadly. You cannot stop anyone from doing something stupid, you can hopefully reduce the risk of injury/death.

Comment: @FedericoRusso, please see my comment to Stevenvh

Comment: +1 on Kortuk's comment... it's useful and educational to list out the dangers to avoid (in this case, that clenching the live wires).

Comment: @FedericoRusso - It would be nice if you actually read the answer properly if you are going to vote on it. I said " ... life and death situation ..." YUour response is unreasonable.  | There is a fire behind you. As you  run electricaal wiring is shorting and the lights are going out. You come to a metal door with a metal knob. Is it live? "YOU" grab the knob. It's live. You die. Others have read my post. They test as instructed, find it is live and take suitable precautions. This slows them down and they would rather have just opened the door but are pleased to know it is live.

Comment: @FedericoRusso - A 230V power line has fallen on somebody and they lie under it tyitching. You wonder if the line is still live or not. (1) You decide it is not. It is. You die. (2) You decide it is. You go to get suitable equipment to deal with it. The line is not live. The person has sewallowed their tongue. By the time you get back they are dead. | Both instances are contrived but the real world often works this way in general. Failing to tell people how to deal with dangers is irresponsible.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: The post was modified significantly after my comment: 1) it now says life-or-death situation. 2) it first said "more safely" and now rightly includes "not totally safe". Important: even in a life-or-death situation this is not safe and may be harmful to the person to the rescue.

Comment: @FedericoRusso - If you are going to quote what the post did say you want to quote what it originally said, which was: "If you ever MUST use your body to test for a live conductor situation (nd and you'd really be better restricting this to life and death situations then ... ADVICE ... 
Note that the above will PROBABLY keep you from dying - but please do not complain to me if it doesn't.

When doing anything as silly And inadvised as this iT pays to have a second person present and NOT touching you when you do this AND ensure they are trained how to handle an electric shock situation.."

Comment: @FedericoRusso - ie it was CLEARLY advice for an extreme emergency situation (that's what "life and death situations" means, AND I also noted that you MAY die doing this and noted it was a "don't complain if you do" situation. SO I find your complaint quite inappropriate. The sort of cotton woolling that does not dicuss worst case scenarios kills people. If stairs are on fire / aircraft brakes up on landing / car is submerged / friend is convulsing / smoke is too acrid to breathe ...// then please just die without making an effort. Have a nice day. Yes?

Answer (score 9):

Wow, that is really irresponsible!

It's dumb enough to check for power or bad grounding by touching the panel himself, but putting the customer at risk is additionally stupid, irresponsible, and probably criminal (seriously).  If you got hurt by this process, you'd probably have a very good legal case.  Even so, you should report this to the local licensing authority.  You'll be doing all the other people he might try this on a favor.  Sooner or later he's going to hurt someone.